# Does Roslyn provides simple way to find compatible method in ClassDeclarationSyntax?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I need to find a compatible method, if exists, in a class code. Is there some simpler way in Roslyn to do that otherwise I have to compare method names, number and types of arguments. It wouldn't be a big deal if we would not have to deal with arguments' non-fully qualified types and inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn provides all the pieces you need. You might want to look at the [SymbolEquivalenceComparer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Shared/Utilities/SymbolEquivalenceComparer.cs) that lives in the Roslyn codebase (but it's not public) for inspiration on how to do the comparison. You'll have to do the comparison checks yourself, but that should be a whopping 20 lines of code or so if you do it right.

As an important note, make sure you're working with the [semantic model](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/) of Roslyn versus just syntax. You mentioned non-qualified types -- as long as you're working with semantics syntax differences like that are taken care of for you.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I'll give it a try